# How to load registered COM DLL in C++

Tags: c++, dll, windows-7, com

I have a `C++ COM dll` and I have register it with `regsvr32`. I want tho use the functions and class of the dll Inside my code. Unfortunatly I dont possess any `.h` and it doesnt come with  a `.tlb` file. I have the documentation how to use the functions and class but there is no information about how to link the dll to my project so I could use it. I am new with using external COM interface so i'm not quite sur where I could find this information.

I have tried `#import "example.dll"` (dll inserted in the project folder but it looks like it doesn't work I have an unable to load dll error. My program is mixed CLR / unmanaged C++.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the documentation contain all the methods and their signatures? In the same order as they are int he interfaces? If so, you should be able to write your own `.h` file. Otherwise you're going to have a hard time...

Comment: Yeah all the definition and declaration is Inside the documentation So i must reproduce the .h by myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If enough information is provided, you can define the interfaces in a header file yourself. I would recommend using `#import` to import an existing COM type library and investigate the generated `.tlh` file for ideas. For a simple interface with functions, for example, the code looks something like this:

```
struct __declspec(uuid("Interface-Guid-with-Dashes")) IInterfaceName : IUnknown
{
  virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_Value (/*[out,retval]*/ long * result) = 0;
  virtual HRESULT __stdcall Execute (/*[in]*/ int value) = 0;
};
```